# Inherit from virtual class and non virtual class

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism

class Rectangle : public virtual Shape

class Rectangle : public Shape

What is the difference between this two classes that inherit from Shape??

Comment: Search StackOverflow for virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Things are not much different if you stop with just these two classes `Rectangle` and `Shape`. [Virtual inheritance](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html) is helpfull in solving the [Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem).